# Android Parsing XML to make a tree

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I am not very old in android development, for the first time I am using XML parsing I am using [this](http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html) tutorial for the parsing the following file that i want to read in a tree structure, I am not able to get some tutorial to parse the file of my requirements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
    <ItemData>
        <title>Fruit</title>
        <level>1</level>

        <ItemData>
            <title>Apple</title>
            <level>2</level>
        </ItemData>

        <ItemData>
            <title>Mango</title>
            <level>2</level>
        </ItemData>

        <ItemData>
            <title>Banana</title>
            <level>2</level>
        </ItemData>

    </ItemData>


    <ItemData>
        <title>Vegitables</title>
        <level>1</level>
        <ItemData>
            <title>carrot</title>
            <level>2</level>
        </ItemData>

        <ItemData>
            <title>spinach</title>
            <level>2</level>
        </ItemData>
    </ItemData>

</Items>
```

I just need guidance and sample code to implement my required functionality. I shall be very grateful.

Comment: You can use either a DOM or a SAX parser. What is not clear to me is what is it you are trying to achieve. Do you need to build the tree and keep the structure in memory so you can scan through it (use DOM parser), or you just want to scan through the xml structure and do not need to keep the whole tree in memory (use SAX in such case)? and what problems are you facing while using the SAX parser?

Comment: I am not able to get a proper example/tutorial how to use sax to recursively parse the xml content in shape of the tree.

Comment: what do you mean a shape of tree?

Comment: I made little research regarding the efficiency of DOM and SAX that concluded that SAX is much better DOM is kinda slow ... What problem I am facing is that I am not able to find any appropriate tutorial to fulfill my requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in that case I think you can use one of the following parser resources to check out a working sample:

1. SAX project: [Quick start guide](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html)
2. A more detailed and extensive explanation of how SAX works, with code samples: [Sun tutorials](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/xmljava/ch03.pdf)
3. Tutorial with DOM vs SAX diff and samples : [more on DOM and SAX](http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html#6.1.2)

Hope above helps. It might help if you post some of errors you are facing?

Comment: I ve pasted a new question would you please help me with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269077/reading-local-xml-source-not-found