# Reading Local XML - Source Not Found

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am trying to read a resource of an XML file but I am getting error "Source Not Found", I am pasting my code beneath, please tell me where I am doing wrong

```
public void ParseXmlFile() {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            dom = db.parse((InputStream) context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.wrist));

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am placed "wrist.xml" in res/xml folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the XML in res/raw folder and use db.parse(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wrist));

Comment: What does the IOException say? I tried the code and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks I just changed the folder name from xml to raw and its working :S ... but thanks for help!!